# Unable to scrape data from from a goverment website featuring a dashboard, having multiple pages, all with same URL

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Trying to scrape data from the website https://www.pmfby.gov.in/adminStatistics/dashboard. Upon clicking the link, Screenshot 1 opens

[image]

What I am trying to scrape is starts from second screen (Refer Screenshot 2)

[image]

There is a list of states. Each state has 5 sub sections. From the drop down menu Featuring Season, I was trying to do for both Rabi and Kharif.

Since the URL is same for all the pages, I tried scraping all the tables. I used below code:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# create a webdriver object and launch the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# navigate to the website
driver.get("https://www.pmfby.gov.in/adminStatistics/dashboard")

# wait for the table to load
table = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "dataTable"))
)

# find all the rows in the table
rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

# loop through each row and print the data
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for col in cols:
        print(col.text)
```

But it gave the following error:-

```
TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x002D37D3]
    (No symbol) [0x00268B81]
    (No symbol) [0x0016B36D]
    (No symbol) [0x0019D382]
    (No symbol) [0x0019D4BB]
    (No symbol) [0x001D3302]
    (No symbol) [0x001BB464]
    (No symbol) [0x001D1215]
    (No symbol) [0x001BB216]
    (No symbol) [0x00190D97]
    (No symbol) [0x0019253D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0054ABF2+2510930]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00578EC1+2700065]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0057C86C+2714828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00383480+645344]
    (No symbol) [0x00270FD2]
    (No symbol) [0x00276C68]
    (No symbol) [0x00276D4B]
    (No symbol) [0x00280D6B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76F800F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77677BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77677B8E+238]
    (No symbol) [0x000000
```

I also tried using Class Name but got same error

Comment: I don't see you clicking on anything to move to another page.

Comment: I have a link to a completely different page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems: (1) the link "State Wise Report" is not clicked, hence the table you want to scrape doesn't load (2) the table you want to scrape doesn't have an id attribute

```
<table class="adminStatics__dashboardTableDT___1cEkH table table-bordered">
```

hence "dataTable" doesn't work. Since is the only table in the page, we can simply use the xpath `//table`.

```
# navigate to the website
driver.get("https://www.pmfby.gov.in/adminStatistics/dashboard")

# click on State Wise Report
link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='State Wise Report']")))
link.click()

# wait for the table to load
table = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table")))

# find all the rows in the table
rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

# loop through each row and print the data
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for col in cols:
        print(col.text)
```

Using `pandas` you can easily scrape the table and get it in a handy format

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
```

[image]